# Metro-Bundler doesn't automatically open

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, expo, metro-bundler

I'm new to react native and just started with the installations and set up; when I reach to the `expo start` or `npm start`] command, in most videos it shows that a page automatically opens on browser *localhost:19002* but for me after several times all I get is [image: metro-bundler-error]

Would be really helpful if someone can direct me on what I should do.

Comment: that's not an error picture just press `a` to start on android or `w` for web.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The Expo CLI Web UI( the page which automatically opens on browser localhost:19002) is deprecated and in the new version of expo is no longer available.
Just use terminal UI and tap `?` in the terminal to see the available options

Comment: Here is the reason why --> https://blog.expo.dev/sunsetting-the-web-ui-for-expo-cli-ab12936d2206

Thanks! I guess I will stop searching where it has gone.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to install react-native-web@~0.18.10, react-dom@18.2.0,
@expo/webpack-config@^18.0.1 by running:

npx expo install react-native-web@~0.18.10 react-dom@18.2.0
@expo/webpack-config@^18.0.1

and then press w to open in your web